# Avoiding governor limits, best way to query with filters?

Tags: apex, soql

So, I'm querying these records, but also filtering out based on UserAccess. While this works, I ran into issues where sometimes I hit the governor limits and got the unfortunate error.

I've tried with Map, but found myself still eventually looping over everything in a for loop based on the IDs in the map. Any suggestions on how to better code for this query?

```
    List<cObject__c> scores = [SELECT Id, Name, Contact__r.Name, Contact__r.Id FROM cObject__c 
                                   WHERE Contact__r.Email = :pageContact.Email];

    List<Id> relScores = new List<Id> (); // List to store contact IDs
    List<cObject__c> fScores = new List<cObject__c>();
    Id contactId;
    Integer count = -1;
    UserRecordAccess access = null;

    for (Integer i = 0; i < scores.size(); i++) {
        contactId = scores[i].Contact__r.Id;
        if (contactId != null) {
            relScores.add(contactId);
        }
    }

    for (Id c : relScores) {
        count++
        try {
            access = [SELECT RecordId, HasReadAccess FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId = :currentUserId AND RecordId = :c];
        } catch (Exception e) {
            continue;
        }
        if (access.HasReadAccess == True) {
            try {
                fScores.add([SELECT Id, Name, Contact__r.Name FROM cObject__cScore__c WHERE Contact__r.Email = :pageContact.Email AND Id = :scores[count].Id]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                continue;
            }
        } else {
            continue;
        } 
    }
    return fScores;
```

Comment: Assuming you use `public with sharing class XYZ`, you don't need to do this at all. Just query the records.

Comment: I did try that as well, but got an error when loading the element on the page. Something like "too many records returned".

Comment: You don't need to query UserRecordAccess at all (which I presume is where the error came from) as long as you're using "with sharing."

Comment: I'm pretty certain I tried it with:

cObject__c[] scores = [SELECT Name, Contact__r.Name, Contact__r.UserRecordAccess.HasReadAccess 
                       FROM cObject__c 
                       WHERE Contact__r.Email = :pageContact.Email];

return scores;

So it was still querying everything without filter, and with sharing unfortunately did not do the trick, unless I missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `currentUserId` is the same as `UserInfo.getUserId()`, you can query this directly on the first step:

```
cObject__c[] scores = [SELECT Name, Contact__r.Name, Contact__r.UserRecordAccess.HasReadAccess 
                       FROM cObject__c 
                       WHERE Contact__r.Email = :pageContact.Email];
cObject__c[] fScores = new cObject__c[0];
for(cObject__c record: scores) {
    if(record.Contact__r.UserRecordAccess.HasReadAccess) {
        fScores.add(record);
    }
}
```

This is now just a single query with no maps.

Comment: Actually, does not seem to filter anything out. All records now appear. Doing the query in the dev console, it seems that Contact__r.UserRecordAccess.HasReadAccess is returning [object Object] rather than 'true' or 'false'

Comment: @CCrenshaw the developer console can't handle references more than one object away. Try using execute anonymous or creating a debug log.

Comment: Interesting. I will have to figure out why it's not filtering records that the user has no access to then. The code looks like it should be working.